# How I can c_char_p value get as a bytes in python3 ctypes?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, ctypes

I have a question about ctypes in python3.

I am trying to get a c_char_p as a python bytes object.
The following code is trying to get its value as a python3 bytes object.

How to get its value as bytes object?

```
from ctypes import *

libc = cdll.LoadLibrary("libSystem.B.dylib")
s1 = create_string_buffer(b"abc") # create a null terminated string buffer
s2 = create_string_buffer(b"bc")  # same at above


g = libc.strstr(s1, s2)  # execute strstr (this function return character pointer)
print(g) # print the returned value as integer
matched_point = c_char_p(g) # cast to char_p
print(matched_point.value) # trying to getting value as bytes object (cause segmentation fault here)
```

Comment: Code looks ok and it worked for me. Strange. And `g` is not a null pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer of the question myself.

According to official Python ctypes documentation, called C function return the integer by default.

So When before calling C function, specify the type of return value with `restype` attribute.

correct code example:

```
from ctypes import *

libc = cdll.LoadLibrary("libSystem.B.dylib")
s1 = create_string_buffer(b"abc") # create a null terminated string buffer
s2 = create_string_buffer(b"bc")  # same at above


libc.strstr.restype = c_char_p # specify the type of return value  

g = libc.strstr(s1, s2)  # execute strstr (this function return character pointer)
print(g) # => b"bc"      (g is bytes object.)
```

Comment: In addition, use `libc.strstr.argtypes = c_char_p,c_char_p` and just call with `g = libc.strstr(b'abc',b'bc')`.  You only need to `create_string_buffer` to create a writable buffer.  `strstr` takes const char pointers, so it's not needed.